# NSOutlineView EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash on expand

Tags: swift, cocoa, xcode7, nsoutlineview

I am trying to use an `NSOutlineView` in my project, using **Swift**.
I have done this a few times already using **Objective-C** without any problem, but for some reason now my app keeps crashing with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`, mostly when trying to expand a cell.

I have created a new test project with only an outline view and the 4 data source methods, but the **crashes** happen, there, too.

Here is the minimal implementation:

```
func outlineView(outlineView: NSOutlineView, numberOfChildrenOfItem item: AnyObject?) -> Int {

    return 3
}

func outlineView(outlineView: NSOutlineView, child index: Int, ofItem item: AnyObject?) -> AnyObject {

    return "Test"
}

func outlineView(outlineView: NSOutlineView, isItemExpandable item: AnyObject) -> Bool {

    return true
}

func outlineView(outlineView: NSOutlineView, objectValueForTableColumn tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, byItem item: AnyObject?) -> AnyObject? {

    return nil
}
```

Any idea of what I am doing wrong?

I have uploaded the test project here. Please review it. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzEhecUbyNeFS3JGN1V0SlJ0dWM/view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things I had to fix to make your sample work as expected:

- There's a crash related to "Test" being a local string and released before the outline view tries to retain it.  This is fixed by having the items owned by the view controller.
- After that, I encountered a crash due to infinite recursion.  That was fixed by having a data model instead of telling the outline view that every item had 3 children no matter what level the item was at.
- I also changed the items to be instances subclassed from NSObject rather than String because I remember reading that that was necessary.  (I currently can't find the reference.)